# Careers bug: new experience has the wrong move arrow and its behavior is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When adding a new job experience to my profile the only move arrow I get is the option to move it down. However, it's a newly added experience, so it's already at the bottom of the list. It should give me an option to move it up, not down.

[image: Newly added experience with a move down arrow only]

Clicking on the arrow incorrectly moves the experience down and shows a popup that says:

> "Sorry, we couldn't move the section."

Despite that, it actually moves the section below the "add experience" link:

[image: Section moved below add experience link]

Comment: Yes, this is a bug and will be fixed. As a workaround, the arrows are correct after a page refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little bit of jQuery tuning... all the arrows should now point into the right direction.